# How to sort a list by a specific index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
list1=[('Oliver', 75, 180), ('Jack', 90, 190), ('Harry', 75, 175), ('Jacob', 60, 175), ('Charlie', 80, 180), ('Thomas', 70, 180)]

sorted(list1 , key = itemgetter(2 , 1) , reverse=True)
```

i wanted if persons height the same the person with less weight printed above
my code output:

```
[('Jack', 90, 190), ('Charlie', 80, 180), ('Oliver', 75, 180), ('Thomas', 70, 180), ('Harry', 75, 175), ('Jacob', 60, 175)]
```

my desire output:

```
[('Jack', 90, 190), ('Thomas', 70, 180),('Oliver', 75, 180),('Charlie', 80, 180), ('Jacob', 60, 175), ('Harry', 75, 175)]
```

i use python3

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @ScottHunter  python3

Comment: @DirtyBit i edit my question

Comment: I can’t spot the difference between what you get and what you want. Which of those two numbers is the “height” and “weight”…?

Comment: So it seems you want to sort first by height (descending) and then as secondary criterion by weight (ascending). Correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
sorted(list1 , key = lambda x: (x[2], -x[1]) , reverse=True)
```

Output

```
[('Jack', 90, 190),
 ('Thomas', 70, 180),
 ('Oliver', 75, 180),
 ('Charlie', 80, 180),
 ('Jacob', 60, 175),
 ('Harry', 75, 175)]
```

This will sort the list by the highest height and the lowest weight in case of the same height.